# How can I do a Preload() with a Raw() in Gorm?

Tags: go, go-gorm

Previously on my project, I needed to do some complex queries so I used `Raw()`. The query looks like this:

```
SELECT tbl1.id, tbl1.some_name, tbl5.some_status, tbl1.some_tbl2_id, tbl1.type_id, tbl1.created_at, tbl5.name
FROM table1 tbl1
JOIN table2 tbl2 ON tbl1.some_tbl2_id = tbl2.id
JOIN table3 tbl3 ON tbl3.edge_device_info_id = tbl2.id
JOIN table4 tbl4 ON tbl4.id = tbl3.account_id
LEFT JOIN table5 tbl5 ON tbl5.tbl1_id = tbl1.id
WHERE tbl5.tbl1_id IS NULL OR tbl5.updated_at = (
    SELECT MAX(updated_at)
    FROM table5
    WHERE tbl1_id = tbl1.id
)
ORDER BY tbl1.created_at ASC;
```

I'm not quite sure if I can do that completely with the stuff/methods from `gorm` so I just went with what I'm more familiar with which is just plain queries. Now, I want to get a the record associated with `tbl1.type_id`. I tried adding a `Preload()` before `Raw()` but that doesn't seem to work as checking the contents of the array of structs I made to store the result of the query doesn't seem to have a filled up `Type`.

UPDATE:

After looking around, I found a way to convert the `Raw()` query above to `gorm`'s method chaining. And it looks like this:

```
Model(models.ActuatorDeviceInfo{}).Preload("ActuatorDeviceInfo.Type").
Select("actuator_device_infos.*, actuator_device_infos.id, at.*").
Joins("JOIN edge_device_infos edi ON actuator_device_infos.parent_edge_device_id = edi.id").
Joins("JOIN user_owned_edge_devices ae ON ae.edge_device_info_id = edi.id").
Joins("JOIN accounts acc ON acc.id = ae.account_id").
Joins("JOIN actuator_types at ON at.id = actuator_device_infos.type_id").
Joins("LEFT JOIN actuator_updates au ON au.actuator_device_info_id = actuator_device_infos.id").
Where("au.actuator_device_info_id IS NULL OR au.updated_at = (?)",
    helpers.GetDB().Model(&models.ActuatorUpdate{}).Select("MAX(updated_at)").
    Where("au.actuator_device_info_id = actuator_device_infos.id")).
Order("actuator_device_infos.created_at DESC").
Scan(&actuator_device_infos)
```

It works just like the previous `Raw()` query, but it's still missing something, and that is the way to get an associated table to table1 (it is actuator_device_infos on the method chaining, kinda lazy to still clean the new code). Even if I add a `Preload()` before the query building methods, it doesn't seem to affect the resulting records. And I needed to use `Model()` for the method chaining as well as it's absence would create an error as the resolved table from `Model()` would be used on the `FROM` part of the final query, so `gorm` should be somewhat aware that the thing I want to preload exist. The thing I preload is `actuator_types`, and it already have a `Joins()` for it, as you can see in the code above.

Comment: Hi, the `Preload` method only works when use like `Find | First` methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Trock's comment, I finally found the last piece of the puzzle. It seems like I just need to use `Find()` at the end of the method chain so `Preload()` would work. The final code looks just like the code I have on my question but I replaced the `Scan()` with `Find()`. And I tried to do the same for the `Raw()` code, and it worked as well. `gorm` should've mentioned that mechanism.